# How to get specific keys from object? (JS)

Tags: javascript, json, object

I have this object:

```
728394 : {
    "playersAmount" : 2,
    "players" : {
      "LRFe9w9MQ6hf1urjAAAB" : {
        "nickname" : "spieler1",
        "type" : "player1"
      },
      "nKUDWEd5p_FCBO4sAAAD" : {
        "nickname" : "spieler2",
        "type" : "player2"
      },
      "ghdaWSWUdg27sf4sAAAC" : {
        "nickname" : "spieler3",
        "type" : "spectator"
      }
    },
    "activePlayer" : "LRFe9w9MQ6hf1urjAAAB",
    "board" : [
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    ]
  }
```

How do I get everything of the object above except for the k/v pair "board"? is there any other way than just adding every key except the right one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a copy and then delete the unwanted key:

```js
const copy = { ...original }
delete copy.unwantedProperty
```

Of course you can instead delete the property on the original if you don't care about mutating it.

(Note: if your environment doesn't support the syntax `{ ...original }`, you can use `Object.assign({}, original)` instead.)

EDIT: Actually, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61733642/1871033) is even neater.

Comment: In case ES6 can't be used: `var copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(original)); delete copy.unwantedProperty;`

Comment: That is much slower though and will destroy anything that cannot be represented with JSON, such as dates, functions, etc.

Answer (score 3):

```
  const { board, ...everythingButBoard } = yourObject
```

Comment: Actually that's a really cool use of destructuring that I didn't think about! Neater than my answer.

Answer (score 1):

simple answer will be:

```
const copyObject = Object.assign({}, yourObject) // to make a copy of original variable
delete copyObject['keyToRemove'] // OR delete copyObject.keyToRemove
```

else if you want to delete from original variable:

```
delete yourObject['keyToRemove'] // OR delete yourObject.keyToRemove
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a new object excluding this key using a for...in

```js
object = {
  wantedKey: 'wantedValue',
  wantedKey2: 'wantedValue2',
  wantedKey3: 'wantedValue3',
  unwantedKey: 'unwantedValue'
}
const newObject = {}
for (const key in object) {
  if (key !== 'unwantedKey') newObject[key] = object[key]
}
console.log(newObject)
```

for more info about for...in: [click here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)